# Ошибка в Quaternion.Lerp

Tags: c#, unity3d

Выскакивает ошибка, никак не могу исправить. На работу вроде не влияет, но их много очень вылетает. (Assertion failed: Assertion failed on expression: '!CompareApproximately(aScalar, 0.0F)'
UnityEngine.Quaternion:Lerp(Quaternion, Quaternion, Single)
Swipe:FixedUpdate() (at Assets/scripts/Swipe.cs:36)
)

```
public class Swipe : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler {
    Vector2 delta;
    Quaternion originRotation;
    Quaternion rotateY;
    Quaternion rotateX;
    GameObject Camera;

    Quaternion targetRot;

    private void Start()
    {
        Camera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

        delta = eventData.delta;
        delta.x = Mathf.Clamp(delta.x, -2f, 2f);
        delta.y = Mathf.Clamp(delta.y, -2f, 2f);
        originRotation = Camera.transform.rotation;
        rotateY = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-delta.y, Vector3.right);
        rotateX = Quaternion.AngleAxis(delta.x, Vector3.up);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() 
    {

          targetRot = originRotation * Quaternion.Euler(-delta.y, delta.x, 0f) ;
          Camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRot, 1);
          Camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Camera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, Camera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0.0f);



    }


}
```

Comment: какая из представленных строк под номером 36?

Comment: предпоследняя строка

Comment: там точно всегда стоит 1? не верю..... попробуй `1.0f`....... но скорее всего там что-то другое вместо константного числа

Comment: Там должно быть time.deltatime, но т.к. Метод fixedupdatw, то поставил просто единицу

Comment: есть еще такая штука как Time.fixedDeltaTime. Но именно как раз из-за нее (из-за time) и  вываливается ошибка... потому что третий параметр должен варьироваться от 0 до 1. А deltatime и fixedDeltaTime - соответственно выходят за 1 и появляется ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Замени `Quaternion targetRot;` на `Quaternion targetRot = Quaternion.identity;`